# UITableViewCell width issue using Xcode 6 Beta - using Size Classes

Tags: uitableview, swift, autolayout, xcode6

I'm tring to come up with a very simple UITableView using Xcode 6 Size Classes. I'm using Any/Any for width and height and the UITableViewCell has just one UILabel having four Constraints (just for leading/trailing space, there's no Width constaint).Now, when running on iPhone simulator, the label's width seems to be unaffected by the iPhone screen real state.

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 4. Is this a bug in Xcode6?

[image: app running in iPhone simulator in Portrait mode]
[image: Size Inspector]

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that autoresizing of views in the contentView of a cell does not work in Xcode 6.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Hey ! Yes I finally did it, check it out, it supports iOS 7 and iOS 8. [Basic Reddit Client in Swift](https://github.com/christ776/MyFirstSwiftProject)

Comment: set constraints for tableview

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a "leading space to container" constraint on both sides while editing the UI in Any/Any or an iPhone-like aspect-ratio. Additionally you could delete the "trailing space to container" constraint.

Comment: It looks like the tableView itself was lacking size constraints, as I noticed they were missing, and now it looks much better though the labels are still not big enough, maybe I'll have to add preferredMaxLayoutWidth ? Thanks! ![link](http://i.imgur.com/gK9t4wF.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "not big enough"? Could you explain how it is supposed to look like?

Comment: I added a call to preferredMaxLayout like this  
`override func layoutSubviews() {  
        redditTitle.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = redditTitle.bounds.width  
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()  
    }`  
  
here's an screenshot : [link](http://i.imgur.com/Dvr8zEw.png)